# puppet dashboard - should generate SHA256 certificate to puppet master

Tags: openssl, ssl-certificate, puppet-enterprise

so I have been trying to bring the puppet dashboard UI up on my server and it is just not happening.

i bumped into [this](http://devsops.blogspot.in/2013/04/installing-puppet-dashboard.html) article which says I need to sign th epuppet dashboard with puppet master which is one thing I had not done.

so I generated the certificate to puppet master and at puppet master I see the certificate is in MD5 format. but the puppet master can sign only SHA256 certificates.

so here, the dashboard is acting like an agent to the puppet master and as per I checked on google, only old agents generated certificates in MD5. and to over come this I have to upgade my agent ( in this case, the dashboard if I am not wrong). how can I upgrade the puppet-dashboard so it will generate a SHA256 key.

some links which I have referred

https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-2992

https://serverfault.com/questions/660649/puppet-master-3-6-2-error-on-signing-puppet-client-2-7-25

https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-3176

Answer (score 0):

So this question did not get any responses and i have quit trying on this and have installed puppet Enterprise. It is very easy with the PE. you just need to download and install. wonderful documentations are easily available on google.